# Greek letters in a GUI - PYTHON

Tags: python, tkinter

I don't know how to write Greek letters in a GUI. I am working on a Physics program and I need to show units on the GUI.

Do I have to download any extra libraries? Is there a module I have to use? What is the easiest way to write the letters in the GUI?

I read a lot about UTF8 but didn't figure out how to use it.

I am using Tkinter for the GUI

I am using Python 2.6.6

Thanks

Comment: Please include the code you've tried.

Comment: I haven't tried. I don't even know what code to use. I don't know anything about this particular question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) includes definitions for both the Greek alphabet and several mathematical symbols. If you are using any form of Unicode in your environment, it should be simple:

```
>>> from Tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> w = Label(root, text=u"Hello, \u03bc-world!")
>>> w.pack()
>>> root.mainloop()
```

This will print "Hello, μ-world!" in a Tkinter window.

Comment: On the Unicode table I have, "micro" (U+B5) is actually distinct from Greek "mu" (U+3BC). Ohms is U+2126 (Mhos is U+2127, but you should be using Siemens (S) instead).

Answer (score 1):

IDLE uses Tkinter, Greek letters seem to work fine in there for me

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

    ****************************************************************
    Personal firewall software may warn about the connection IDLE
    makes to its subprocess using this computer's internal loopback
    interface.  This connection is not visible on any external
    interface and no data is sent to or received from the Internet.
    ****************************************************************

IDLE 2.6.5      
>>> print "Ω ω"
Ω ω
>>>
```

If you wish to use unicode literally in your source, you should include a line like this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

At the top of each file

Comment: As long as the OP has setup a Greek keyboard layout. Unicode code escapes are harder to use but far more portable when included in source code.

Comment: @thkala, I copied and pasted them from the wikipedia page :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_letters

Comment: @thkala, I wouldn't say "far more". Python3 supports unicode _identifiers_. If you're still using an environment that doesn't do utf-8 it's time to consider upgrading

Comment: I had actually prepared my Tkinter Hello-World with literal greek letters - *then* it occured to me that the OP might not have a greek layout as I do, or even a font with greek glyphs in their IDE - hence the escapes...

Comment: Oh, I'm all set - but then I paste a piece of code on the Web and *things* start to happen :-)...

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print( u'\u03a9' )
Ω
```

Works for me.

What **specific** problem are you having?

Comment: That helped. I didn't know it was that easy. The examples I saw had encode, decode...blla blla blla stuff in them. Can I do : mystring = '('u\u03a9')'

Comment: "Can I do..."?  Try it.  Report back on what happened.  I don't really understand the overall question.

Comment: Neverming my question. I was trying to put '('u\u03a9')' on a string variable so I can work with it easily. Figured it out, though. Thanks!