# When I type non-ASCII characters using a Windows keyboard I get "?"

Tags: python, unicode, tkinter, keyboard

When I type `non-ASCII` characters using a Windows keyboard (in the language bar), I get question marks `?` where the non-ASCII characters should go.

Copy-and-paste works fine and the Unicode characters are displayed in the `Text` widget.

I am using the `Lakota All-In-One keyboard` found [here](http://www.languagegeek.com/siouan/keyboards/si_kbds.html). This particular keyboard is listed in the *Windows language bar* under the `US` locale.

Comment: If I switch the language from my keyboard from US to CANADA-FRENCH the key for `é` still works as if it was the ? key. I don`t know if that`s any help at all.

Comment: Good question... It's not the question mark key that I am typing. Instead, any non-ASCII character that I type is convert to a question mark.

Comment: Tkinter is extremly out dated. I would recommend learning a new library to create GUI's, one that has a bigger community.

Comment: For the purpose of testing, try to set the default value of the text widget to `u'\u0160kte \u0161ni'` which should print `Škáte šni`. I also recommend trying to type the Unicode characters [directly](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) just to make sure that the keyboard layout is not the culprit. Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6604865/2016778).

Comment: Shervin, I will try typing the Unicode in directly...I haven't had time to try it out yet. From the Python code it is relatively easy to get Unicode to show up. The keyboard input is where I am having problems. I wonder if I can somehow intercept the keyboard input, to provide the Unicode handling. When I circle back around to this part of the project hopefully I can make some headway.

Comment: Crispy, I'm not sure your response is relevant to my question, but you have me curious now. What GUI system(s) would you recommend? I am always open to learning new systems.

Comment: @BiagioArobba. I rechecked the keyboard layout and it seems be Unicode-complaint. More on Tkinter and Unicode [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036499/special-characters-aeoa-in-tkinter-entry-get).

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using Python 2.7.3 (32-bit)

Comment: I'm late but what do you mean with *"When I type non-ASCII characters"*? Do you typed it in the text box or in the script which is displayed in your text widget?

Comment: check if your GUI framework had proper unicode support, or wide character. or if you had proper fonts to display that.

Answer (score 1):

TkInter doesn't seem too good with special characters, especially on Fedora. I've seen dozens of posts like this. Your best bet might be to use another GUI library, like [PyFLTK](http://pyfltk.sourceforge.net/)(my favorite), [GTK+ 3](https://live.gnome.org/PyGObject)(my second favorite), [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro), [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide), [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org), [Kivy](http://kivy.org), etc.

Comment: That's not really a helpful answer. It's actually a bug _in TkInter itself_ that it gets Unicode handling wrong.

Comment: @DonalFellows: I know it's a bug in TkInter. I said "especially on Fedora" because most of the errors involving unicode I find are on Fedora. There's even a special Fedora-only patch I found. Yes, it's that bad. ARGHH!!! The Python devs really need to fix that issue...

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter has a problematic history with unicode. Try entering the full utf value (i.e. \x80abc) I find that that sometimes fixes this problem.